# Overriding dayjs today's value

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetimepicker, dayjs

I have a datepicker component, that uses `dayjs` to manage dates.

I also run Visual Regression tests using Chromatic and have an issue there. Because the today's date is marked in blue, the VR tests fail everyday.

To get today's value I just run the `dayjs()` function

How can I globally override the `dayjs()` default return value to always return the same date, so that other functionality stays the same?

Comment: You could mock the date with this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate

Comment: fixed it by overriding Date.now. Thanks for the answer!